# How can I integrate SQL Server and my android application with Push

Tags: android, asp.net, sql-server

A long time ago I've been reading and watching tutorials about Android, reading about Push Notifications and GCM, but I don't understand.

I have a Order's table in my SQL Server database and an Android application. On every order status update, the application must be notified.

But I don't understand how it works.

I've created an app by GCM in the developers.google, I've got the key, id, etc, but how do I do this integration?

Should I change my database? Should I create a ASP.NET system for notifications when I update my database?

I've tried the Azure push, but it provides a JavaScript or asp.net code. Why this one? Can anyone explain this to me?

I've implemented many codes from tutorials and internet, but there's no SQL Server and Android tutorial. I searched here, someone talked about using trigger, but I don't know how to integrate this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a web service to sit in between the application and the database

You can find some information on web services [Here](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=4TdXVoTrC9fEUKSGkpgI#q=web%20service%20c%5C)

Comment: Thanks, I already worked with WebServices, but I wanna integrate with PUSH notification. I edited my title.

Comment: You will still need a go between, have a look at this, http://www.tejaprakash.com/2013/05/push-messages-to-gcm-server-using-net.html

Answer (score 0):

The database doesn't actually matter.

In order to achieve your goals, you need:

1. Regiester the user's device to GCM, and get his token.
2. Know when you need to send the Push.
3. Send a request to GCM in order to send the push to the device.

You can use any techonology you want, and if you use .NET, you might want to try [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp)

Comment: Hi. I've created a projet in console.developers.google.com. Now I have the Server API Key and the Sender_ID. In Asp.net I found a code with a method  public string SendNotification(string deviceId, string message), but what this device id? How can I pass by asp.net, if I am on the server side? Could you explain this device id? Thanks a LOT!

Comment: You can get all the info needed in the PushSharp link in my answer, check it.